# Access external variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to convert the following pseudo-code to Haskell:

```
stringA = "ABCD"
stringB = "EFGH"
stringC = "ICJK"

function myFunction(String x) {

     otherFunction(x)

}
```

Now, in Haskell I have

```
 stringA = "ABCD";
 stringB = "EFGH";
 stringC = "ICJK";


test :: Int
test x = if x == 1 then otherFunction(??) else ...
```

How can I ensure that otherFunction takes stringA as a paramter when test is called with x = "stringA"?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You have extraneous whitespace in front of your `stringN` definitions.

Answer (score 7):

```
test :: Int
test x = if x == 1 then otherFunction stringA else ...
```

Of course, this is wrong, because test takes a parameter, so it's type must always contain (at least) one (->). But that's not the issue at hand. Strangely you've claimed that your pseudocode function takes a String parameter, which would look like `test :: String -> ...` in Haskell. But you're clearly giving it an Int as its first parameter, meaning its type should be `test :: Int -> ...`

Here's my translation of your pseudocode:

```
stringA = "ABCD"
stringB = "EFGH"
stringC = "ICJK"

test x = otherFunction x
```

Comment: Or just `test = otherFunction`

Answer (score 0):

```
test "stringA" = otherFunction stringA
test "stringB" = otherFunction stringB
test "stringB" = otherFunction stringB
-- etc...
```

As you can imagine this will be a pain to do for more than 3 or 4 cases. What about storing your strings as key/value pairs in a list?

```
test strIn = (liftM otherFunction) lookup strIn dict
   where dict = 
        [("stringA", "ABCD"), ("stringB", "EFGH"), ("stringC", "ICJK")]
```

In general there is no way to convert a string to a function reference at runtime.